# Unusual bugs with my Unix Shell Project, please enlighten me

Tags: c, shell, operating-system

so we are writing a unix shell that is capable of running 11 commands including the commonly known "which" and "where" commands. The odd part is that the two commands work perfectly fine about.. 80% of the time and the rest of the time they return nothing on the UI.

To be clear when I say 80% of the time: I mean once the program is running and where/which works, it will continue to work until the program is exited and re-run for another try. If the program starts and doesn't work, it will continue to not work until the program is exited and re-run for another try.

Also (I'll shed some more info on this below), the shell seg-faults when you hit enter with no command although it will respond correctly when a nonsense command is entered.

I've tried a lot of brute-force guessing for fixes. It's hard to understand why the quality of the functionality is so seemingly random.

Valgrind may have shed some light on an issue which I'll describe after pasting some code below.

```
//inits outside of while loop below

  char *prompt = calloc(PROMPTMAX, sizeof(char));
  char *commandline = calloc(MAX_CANON, sizeof(char));
  char *command, *arg, *commandpath, *p, *pwd, *owd;
  char **args = calloc(MAXARGS, sizeof(char*));
  int uid, i, status, argsct, go = 1;
  struct passwd *password_entry;
  char *homedir;
  char BUFFER[BUFFER_SIZE];
  char PROMPT[BUFFER_SIZE];
  struct pathelement *pathlist;

//inits inside of while loop below

    int wc = 0;
    char *input;
    /* print your prompt */
    printf("%s[%s]>", prompt_prefix, cwd);
    /* get command line and process */
    fgets(BUFFER, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
    char delim[] = " \n\r";
    input = strtok(BUFFER, delim);
    char *cmdArray[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while(input != NULL){
        cmdArray[wc] = input;
    input = strtok(NULL, " \n\r");
    wc++;
    }

//where function below

    char *where(char *command, struct pathelement *pathlist ){
        char BUFFER[BUFFER_SIZE];
        struct pathelement *current = pathlist;

        DIR *dr;
        struct dirent *de;
        strcpy(BUFFER, "");

        while(current != NULL){
            char *path = current->element;
            dr = opendir(path);

            if(dr){
                while((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL){
                    if(strcmp(de->d_name, command) == 0){
                        strcat(BUFFER, path);
                        strcat(BUFFER, "/");
                        strcat(BUFFER, de->d_name);
                        strcat(BUFFER, "\n");
                    }
                }   
            }
            closedir(dr);
            current = current->next;
        }
        int len = (int) strlen(BUFFER);
        char *p = (char *) malloc(len);

        BUFFER[len - 1] = '\0';
        strcpy(p, BUFFER);
        return p;
    }

    //if statement that implements where function

    else if(strcmp(cmdArray[0], commands[2]) == 0){//where command
        if(cmdArray[1] == NULL){
            printf("Failed to run\n");
        }
        else{
            for(int loopCount2 = 1; i < MAXARGS; loopCount2++){
                if(cmdArray[loopCount2] != NULL){
                    char *result = where(cmdArray[loopCount2], pathlist);//loopCount2?
                    if(result != NULL){
                        printf("%s\n", result);
                        free(result);
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("%s not found\n", cmdArray[loopCount2]);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

It's probably important to note that although the functions work most of the time, "valgrind --track-origins=yes ./mysh" raises the following issue 100% of the time:

"Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    at (some hex value) sh (sh.c:155)
    by (some hex value) main (main.c:12)
Uninitialised value was created by stack allocation
    at (some hex value) sh (sh.c:25)"

The odd thing is that when I take a look at the lines that are pointed out by valgrind, they do seem to be values that were in fact initialized (in my very amateur coding opinion)

P.S. I see the last part of the code I'm trying to post isn't formatted well in the preview, I'll try and edit that so it's easy to read soon

Comment: In addition to being too complicated the code is actually *incorrect* logicwise. Instead of using `opendir`/`readdir` you should just form the *path* using each search path, and then use the system call `access` to check if it is ok to *execute* that path.

Comment: And which lines are 155 and 25?

Comment: Tip: You can replace `strcpy(BUFFER, "");` with `BUFFER[0] = 0;`

Comment: Can you please provide code that actually exhibits the problem you are asking about instead of an incomplete program

Comment: Your code finds the first item in a readable directory with the given name, no matter if it is executable or not, or even a file. Executing a command does not require that the containing directory is readable but it sure does require that the file is an executable *file*.

Comment: The lines 155 and 25 point to the line before the else statement in the implementation of where that holds break; and the other points to the line directly before char *prompt = calloc(PROMPTMAX, sizeof(char));

Comment: Please provide an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses;
MCVE was good for over five years and it did not need changing)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).